# GestureRecognizer Swipe Gesture

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying to detect a horizontal swipe gesture with [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.ASPx) by hooking up to the [CrossSliding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.crosssliding.ASPx) event.

```
        _gr = new GestureRecognizer
        {
            GestureSettings = GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateX |
                              GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateY |
                              GestureSettings.CrossSlide
        };

        _gr.CrossSliding += OnSwipe;
        _gr.ManipulationStarted += OnManipulationStarted;
        _gr.ManipulationUpdated += OnManipulationUpdated;
        _gr.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;

        _gr.CrossSlideHorizontally = true;
```

As you can see from the code above, not only swipe should be detected, but also dragging gestures.

My problem is I can't seem to customize the swipe gesture.

I want to customize the minimum speed and distance a user has to drag the pointer before the gesture is considered a swipe. In the current state even the slowest and smallest horizontal drag motion will trigger a `CrossSliding` event.

I saw the [CrossSlideThresholds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.crossslidethresholds.ASPx) class that allows to customize the gesture, but I couldn't see how it could be used to configure speed and distance of the swipe gesture.

Is the `CrossSliding` event the proper way to detect a swipe? If so, how can I configure speed and swipe distance?

If not, how can I detect a swipe gesture?

Comment: What do you understand a swipe to be? I think in Windows 8 case it is what is used to select list items and cross sliding describes this gesture being perpendicular to the panning direction of a `ScrollViewer`. Is that what you are trying to detect?

Comment: no it's not that, i mean a quick horizontal or vertical touch point movement, like you would use to flick through pages of a book or album covers on a device (hope that makes sense). I reread the documentation and came to the conclusion that there is no built in way to detect a swipe. I implemented my own detection and will add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any built in way to detect a swipe, so I implemented my own detection method.

The code detects a horizontal swipe.

The shown methods are the event handlers for the `GestureRecognizer` events:

```
readonly Stopwatch _manipulationTimer = new Stopwatch();

public void OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    _manipulationTimer.Restart();
}

public void OnManipulationCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var millis = _manipulationTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    if (Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Translation.Y) < MaxVerticalSwipeDistanceInPix &&
        Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Translation.X) > MinHorizontalSwipeDistanceInPix && 
        millis > MinSwipeDurationInMillis && 
        millis < MaxSwipeDurationInMillis && 
        Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Scale - 1) < 0.01 // 1 touch point 
        )
    { 
        var leftSwipe = e.Cumulative.Translation.X < 0;
        if (leftSwipe)
        {
        }
        else // right swipe
        {               
        }
    }

    _manipulationTimer.Stop();
    _manipulationTimer.Reset();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good way to do it. Additionally you could just detect a flick by handling the `ManipulationInertiaStarting` event and checking for translation velocities to see the direction of the flick.

Comment: @FilipSkakun thanks for the suggestion, I haven't thought about that